# Trying implement validation on uploaded files (specifically images)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Basically, I want it so that user has to have chosen a file for upload. Then when the user presses the form submit button, it will only be successful if the user has selected a file.

I think I need something like `validates_attachment` in Paperclip, except for carrier wave. The code I post will always render `recipe_images/new` regardless if the user selected an image or not.

Model

```
class RecipeImage < ApplicationRecord
    # upload images
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    validates_presence_of :image
    # associations
    belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Controller

```
class RecipeImagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @recipe_image = RecipeImage.new
    @recipe_id = params[:recipe_id]
    if current_user != Recipe.find(@recipe_id).user
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe_id)
    end
  end

  def create
    @recipe_image = RecipeImage.new(recipe_image_params)
    @recipe_id = params[:recipe_id]
    @recipe = Recipe.find(@recipe_id)
    if @recipe.recipe_images << @recipe_image
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    else
      flash[:recipe_image_create] = 'Please choose an image.'
      render 'recipe_images/new'
    end
  end

  private
    def recipe_image_params
      params.permit(:image)
    end
 end
```

View

```
<% if flash[:recipe_image_create] %>
    <strong><%= flash[:recipe_image_create]%></strong>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@recipe_image, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
  <p>Select Image</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>

  <%= hidden_field_tag 'recipe_id', @recipe_id %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save',{class: 'btn btn-primary'}   %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason creating adding another column to the model fixed this error. Not sure why but I'll take it.